# Bryton Rider 420 not showing vehicles from Garmin Varia radar

Tags: bike-computer

Trying to use the Garmin Varia RTL515 radar with Bryton Rider 420. I have it paired via ANT+ successfully. I get the sound notifications and the black strip shows up on the right side of the display. However I can not see any indications of vehicles on it. Apparently the manual has not been updated after radar support has been added to the device, so I can't tell how it should work exactly. The [web site only says](https://www.brytonsport.com/#/R420) *"While in the Meter Page, the radar strip will display approaching vehicles"*

Sample image of radar strip from manufacturer:

[image: sample image of radar strip]

I assume the little round thing on the bottom right should be a vehicle and it should move up as it approaches, but on my device it stays there. Tried with the radar's demo mode as well. Has somebody got this to work?

Firmware versions (latest as reported by the respective tools):

- Bryton R040.005.0014 EX:05.011.001
- Varia 3.32

Comment: Great question - have you tried reaching out to Garmin and Bryton  ?

Comment: Not yet. I expect Garmin to say "Turn it off and on again. Use Garmin computer." and Bryton to say ... nothing (apparently they don't have a stellar support). Just wanted to collect some data points beforehand about what experience others had, if any.

Comment: I think Bryton should test their 420 with Varia... not sure if they did or miss something to support Varia 515. I'm also using 420 and Varia 515 and have similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bryton created their own version of the radar and probably realized that does not work properly with the 420 either. So they published a new firmware to fix it which also fixes the garmin varia. Yay! Better late than never.

> Firmware version: ⁡ R052.005.0017 EX:05.011.002
>
> ️Improved radar traffic support

Comment: What is that radar actually for? There are cars, trucks going on the roads I ride. I haven't been ran over yet. In what way a radar can help me?

Comment: @Ender It warns you of approaching cars. While this doesn't prevent anybody from close passes or running straight over you, you can at least prepare for it, ride in a straight line and don't reach for your bottle or in your pockets which makes you swerve left/right into the oncoming vehicle. Newer and more advanced iterations of the Varia radars even have cameras that automatically record oncoming vehicles and act as evidence, if jurisdiction allows for it.

Comment: Also the light changes flash mode to better alert the car driver, especially if the speed difference is big. According to my experience, people really seem to overtake more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I have both devices. Bryton connect to varia radar. It show the black line. What happend in my is that when vehicle appear, it show black line and give me tone puls. It does not show vehicle with dot or distance (moving dots like on garmin). After vehicle pass, black line dissapear. Comparable with Fenix 7, it detect correct. Only missing is a little better graphical aproach. But I am satisfy.
What I was not able to do is select light mode of varia with bryton.

Comment: There are two relevant ANT+ protocols: the radar and the smart light protocol. I think most of the non-Garmin manufacturers implemented the radar but *not* the smart light protocol. Thus, you can’t control the light settings from a non-Garmin unit, or even check the battery status on the unit (you can use your smartphone app). It is what it is, as they say.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yes, that is exactly what I see as well. It's also disappointing that you can't turn off the light, not even with the button on the varia itself. You can only choose various lighting modes, but not turn it off. In a group, even the supposed group friendly low power mode gets me complaints so I can't use the radar :/